# How to clear content in timepicker instantly after I changed datepicker?

Tags: google-apps-script, datepicker, timepicker, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm working on a Google calendar add-on with a datepicker and timepicker using CardService. And here's the code.

```
var startDate = CardService.newDatePicker()
  .setTitle("Start Date:")
  .setFieldName("startDate")

var startTime= CardService.newTimePicker()
  .setTitle("Start Time:")
  .setFieldName("startTime")
  .setHours(10)
  .setMinutes(0)
```

I want the timepicker to change instanly after I change the datepicker.
To be more precise, I want the timepicker to be cleared and show as blank when I set the datepicker as today, while show 10:00 AM when I set it as other days.

I was thinking set no default time of the timepicker and change it when I set the datepicker other than today, but at the first place it shows 12:00 AM instead of blank. So it seems that this way doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After please edit your question to include the minimal code to reproduce your question. Thank you.

Comment: @Aerials Thank you for your advice and I just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time picker will always have a value (it can't be blank). If you don't set your own default value by adding hours and minutes, the default will be 00:00 hrs or 12:00 am as it is the start of the day.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! And in addition, I want to ask that whether I can make the timepicker change instantly after I change the datepicker?

Comment: You can use [`setOnChangeAction(action)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-picker#setOnChangeAction(Action)) method for this. Where `action` could be to run a custom function that sets the time picker to your desired time. You may also want to use [`DateTimePicker`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker) istead of Date and Time pickers, but this is a design decision.